# Missing form in magento 1.9 onepage checkout -- not using theme OnePageCheckout

Tags: magento

we are using a theme that has an installed onepagecheckout. however, due to some requirements for our checkout we cant use it and are using the default magento checkout. this is all fine except that we have no coupon form. when i look in the local.xml file the following does not exist

```
<reference name="content">
           <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
               </reference>
```

for checkout_cart_index. it does still exist in the base/layout/checkout.xml file.
in local.xml it does call for

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/coupon.phtml"/>
```

in the onepagecheckout_index_index

the checkout/cart/coupon.phtml file does exist. but the block is not being called on the checkoutpage at all.

how can i add the coupon block back into the magento checkout?

i just saw that the above code puts the block on the cart page not the checkout page. how do i add it to the review section of checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly then you want to add a "discount coupon code block" in your "order review" in one page checkout.In default magento the "discount coupon code block" is in cart page.
To add the block just call that block in "template\checkout\onepage\review.phtml".Just paste the below code in the above mentioned file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

This will bring the coupon block in your order review.

Hope this may help.

Comment: this doesnt work in 1.9 rwd theme. It doesnt output the block unless i also need to declare it in the xml checkout.xml as well?